# application crashes after calling showBanner method of revmob

Tags: objective-c

I integrate revmob in the app for displaying banner. After calling [[RevMobAds session] showBanner] method application crashes.

Comment: put the crash report here

Comment: app is not throwing any exception, it just show 'signal SIGABRT' warning in main class

Comment: Can you post the full log message?